# User with a website as username, answering to a 5 years old question with no content, flag rejected

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I'm quite new to Stack Overflow (as an active member), maybe I'm missing something, but I don't get why my flag as spam was rejected on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62115658/6303541) that I encountered while browsing a review queue (can't remember if *First Posts* or *Late Answers*).

It's a new account with a website as username, he answered a question from 2015 (5 years old as I write) with a one-line answer 90% identical to the previous one (now it's "longer", but you can see the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62115658/revisions)).

Why this can't be considered as spam? What kind contribute does it add to the community?

Comment: There's no spam in the answer. As far as I know, there's no rule against advertising your web site in your user name. As for the answer itself, I don't know Java so I don't know if it's contributing anything, but even if it isn't that would only merit a downvote at most.